# How does autonomy as defined by Kant relate to respect for others?

Tags: kant

I understand what Autonomy means. However, I fail to understand how it maps on to respect for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is described towards the end of the second section of the *Groundwork of the Metaphysics of Morals*.

The definition of autonomy is:

> Autonomy of the will is the characteristic of the will by which it is a law
>   to itself (4:440)

The link between autonomy and respect for others is the defining core of the concept of what he calls *kingdom of ends*:

> **[E]very rational being, as an
>   end in itself, must be able to view itself as at the same time universally legislating** with regard to any law whatsoever to which it may
>   be subject, because it is' just this ﬁttingness of its maxims for universal
>   legislation that marks it out as an end in itself; likewise that **this dignity
>   (prerogative) it  [i.e. a rational being] has above all merely natural beings brings with it that
>   it must always take its maxims from the point of view of itself, but also
>   at the same time of every other rational being as legislating (which are
>   therefore also called persons).** Now in this way **a world of rational beings (mundus intelligibilis) as a kingdom of ends** is possible, and possible
>   through their own legislation of all persons as members. (4:438, bolded mine)

In other words: As autonomy is about the will being a law to itself and is a property of rational beings as such, any "legislating act", i.e. determining how things should be per autonomy, has to consider the autonomy of every other rational being, i.e. **their** *dignity*.

This means that the concept of the autonomy of the will *itself* entails the *respect* for the autonomy of others, i.e. their dignity, *because* autonomy is something that pertains to the will of *every finite rational being*:

> [T]he legislation
>   that determines all worth [i.e. autonomy of the will of a finite rational being] must itself have a dignity, i.e. unconditional,
>   incomparable worth, for which the word *respect* alone makes a beﬁtting
>   expression of the estimation a rational being is to give of it. Autonomy is
>   thus the ground of the dignity of a human and of every rational nature. (4:436)

The reason for *why* it pertains to *every* (finite) rational being is beyond the scope of this question, but comes down to the fact that all the analysis of the second section which *results* in the concept of autonomy *started* with the concept of the will of a (finite) rational being *as such*. Thus, autonomy is a concept *entailed* in the concept of the will of a (finite) rational being and thus trivially pertains to every (finite) rational being. Well, according to Kant's argument, that is.

Comment: Could you give an example, please?